# SQL query using ['id'] GET parameter

Tags: php, mysql, web

looking at the screenshot below, I'm trying to make it so that when you click on "faculty" or "students" or "alumni," the page (people.php) should only return the database results (mysql) that are assigned as such. However, I keep receiving this error message on line 54:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':member'.

Is this because I manually set the 'id' in lines 28-30? I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure it out, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
              echo'<h3 class="panel-title"><a href="people.php?id=faculty">Faculty</a></h3>';
              echo'<h3 class="panel-title"><a href="people.php?id=student">Students</a></h3>';
              echo'<h3 class="panel-title"><a href="people.php?id=alum">Staff</a></h3>';
?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- vvvvvvvvvvvvvv-FACE OF THE ORG-vvvvvvvvvvvvvv -->
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="row">

<?php
if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT first_name, last_name, department, website, filename, membership
                FROM Profile");
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
    echo '<div class="col-sm-3">
            <img class="img-rounded" src="'.$row['filename'].'"/>
            <p class="caption">';
    echo '<a href="'.htmlentities($row['website']).'" target="_blank">'.$row['first_name'].' '.htmlentities($row['last_name']).'</a>';
    echo ', '.htmlentities($row['department']);
    echo '</p> </div>';
  }
```

Comment: Please post your code and not an image of it. Anyway I was curious so I give it a look. If you are posting the data with a form which I beleave has a post method in it, you need to do : if(isset($_POST['id']))

Comment: added the code, thanks! it's getting the data from a get request i believe

Comment: the text code you posted, isn't what you need to put. it's the other one where you're trying to bind the `:member` but didn't prepare the query

Comment: I am curious though, which MySQL API are you using to connect with, is it `mysqli_`, `mysql_` or PDO? even by preparing and not working, is the only reason I can see for it failing like that.

Comment: and those images need to be removed. They're not needed for the error related to this, they take up too much room for nothing.

Comment: if you expect help/solutions, you need to reply here. I'm leaving this question in 2 mins. Most precisely [**this comment...**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185213/sql-query-using-id-get-parameter#comment56117138_34185213) to you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's PDO, you'll understand if you see the naming of the connection variables.

Comment: @TareqMahmood *"Hi Tareq, thanks! I added the code above (does that help?) I also changed $pdo->query to $pdo->prepare, but am getting the same error message – Iz Gao 17 mins ago"* - explain that. No, I'm sure the OP's NOT using PDO to connect with. The error tells me so.

Comment: He has updated in the wrong place and now I don't see that part of code since the image is gone where I saw that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the codes instead of images so that we can help you better. Here what I see is you are using `$pdo->query` instead of `$pdo-prepare` for preparing the statement. Fix it like this :

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT first_name, .......,:member");
$stmt->execute(array(":member"=>$_GET['member']));
```

Comment: Hi Tareq, thanks! I added the code above (does that help?) I also changed $pdo->query to $pdo->prepare, but am getting the same error message

Comment: You need to change the second one where you have :member, not the first one. It's running the query, not creating statement.